# python, vlc, rtsp. Screenshots doesn't work

Tags: python, vlc, rtsp

I run this:

```
import vlc
import time

player = vlc.MediaPlayer('rtsp://NNNNNNNNNNNNNN')
player.play() 

period = 2  # Every 2 seconds I got new screenshot from camera

while True:
    time.sleep(period)
    player.video_take_snapshot(0, 'screenshot-tmp.png', 0, 0)
```

Once I delete `player.play()` - it does not work anymore. No screenshoots.

What the problem?

I don't need to open VLC player, just need to taking screens and work with them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try creating your `player` this way:**

```py
instance = vlc.Instance("--vout=vdummy")
player = instance.media_player_new("rtsp://NNNNNNNNNNNNNN")
player.play()
```

(based on [this](https://github.com/oaubert/python-vlc/issues/64#issuecomment-418640413))

You can't remove `player.play()` because this call is required for the media to start actually playing.

**How the code above works?** To get rid of the GUI we can use the `--vout` VLC CLI argument described [in the docs](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/) as a way to control the video output method. We choose a special one – `vdummy` – so the video output is faked.

CLI-like arguments [can be provided](https://videolan.videolan.me/vlc/group__libvlc__core.html#ga66f3850371cf5ece456f5c45313bb086) when a "libvlc instance" is created, so we do it manually (otherwise you had the default one created automatically, without the `--vout=vdummy`).

Then `media_player_new(uri)` creates a new `MediaPlayer` object off that "libvlc instance". It can be used like any other `MediaPlayer`, but its behavior will be affected by the CLI args we provided to the `Instance`.

Answer (score 1):

By calling play from the player object, a stream starts. The video_take_snapshot method needs of a media player instance for the screenshots to be taken[1].

With other third-party libraries like OpenCV you could use something like VideoCapture of the player without the player starting: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html

```
import vlc
import cv2

url = 'rtsp://NNNNNNNNNNNNNN'

instance = vlc.Instance()

media = instance.media_new(url)

player = vlc.MediaPlayer(media)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(player) 

period = 2

while True:
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  if ret:
    cv2.imwrite('screenshot-tmp.png', frame)
    print("Screenshot captured!")  
  else:
    print("Error capturing frame")
  time.sleep(period)
```

[1]
https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/index.html

Comment: I got:  TypeError: argument of type 'Media' is not iterable